# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure in .Net core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-1.0

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version

The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.2' was not found.

- Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
- Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.2'.

[image]

**I installed [Windows (Server Hosting) installer](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848766) and  [Runtime Installer 64-bit](https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/0/2/D028801E-0802-43C8-9F9F-C7DB0A39B344/dotnet-win-x64.1.1.2.exe) but still facing this issue**

I tired all possible solutions but nothing is working for me

please help me!
Thank You

Comment: Try to install this https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/1.1.2-download.md or update your project deps

Comment: I already installed this on server . but nothing is working still showing same error.

Comment: The one time I dealt with this type of issue, I had mixed architecture; trying to deploy a 32 bit application on a 64 bit OS. Something to check. Once I got them in sync, everything ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your website from the command line with command below:

```
dotnet YourWebApp.dll
```

This way you'll be able to see any errors which may be preventing your website from starting. You can then follow the erros shown and look for their specific fixes.